A Back4app cloud function with flutter returns an empty body/payload
my cloud function
Parse.Cloud.define("paymentRequest", async (request) => {
const {token, amount, number} = request.params;
const autToken = `Token ${token}`;

const headers = {
    'Authorization': autToken,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

const url = `https://demo.campay.net/api/collect/`;

const body = JSON.stringify({
    "amount": amount,
    "from": number,
    "description": "Testing Flipay withdrawal",
    "external_reference": ""
});

try {
    const response = await Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        headers: headers,
        body: body,
    });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(response.text);
        const jbody = JSON.stringify(response.body);
        const data = JSON.parse(jbody);
        const ref = data.reference;
        console.log(`Reference ${ref}`);            
        console.log('paid');
        return ref;
    } else {
        console.error('Request failed with response code:', response.status);
        console.log('not paid');
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Request failed with error:', error);
    console.log('not paid');
    throw new Error('Failed to send payment request');
}

});
the output after been called with the necessary parameters
flutter: ╭-- Parse Request
flutter: curl -X POST -H 'content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' -H 'user-agent: Flutter Parse SDK 5.1.3' -H 'X-Parse-Application-Id: VSywmg8EtB4bhzJzRXuxsjxzLiWBJlEEshZB578K' -H 'X-Parse-Client-Key: qJvcumQMZposWCGayVWfC6GyYSkljB5MijIJ8ALS' -d '{"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsInVpZCI6MzM5NH0.eyJpYXQiOjE3MTYxNTQ5OTAsIm5iZiI6MTcxNjE1NDk5MCwiZXhwIjoxNzE2MTU4NTkwfQ.xrxoGtwsfYR1bktP0EnUOU-6DS3OPQ8SE7X312QHAOU","amount":"100","number":"237678447430"}' https://parseapi.back4app.com/functions/paymentRequest
https://parseapi.back4app.com/functions/paymentRequest
flutter: ╰--
flutter: ╭-- Parse Response
Class: paymentRequest
Function: ParseApiRQ.execute
Status Code: 200
Payload: {}
╰--
i have tried everything i could.
the expected results has to be uuid4 for example: "bcedde9b-62a7-4421-96ac-2e6179552a1a"

It's not safe to share your app credentials here... Have you already tried the Back4app support team? I'm sure they will be able to assist you with it instead of making the app credentials public :)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
